# Speed up scrolling of genlist item?

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

I have a native `genlist` with item style of `1text`.

This style is capable of scrolling when the text is longer than the display, but how can I control the speed? I want it to scroll faster.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Let's figure out how to change the text scroll speed.

The native genlist 1text style edc is implemented in the file below.

Project profile/wearable/platform/core/uifw/efl-theme-tizen-wearable/wearable-circle/widgets/genlist.edc

Branch : tizen

textblock { "elm.text"; scale;
   desc { "default";
      rel1 {
         relative: 1.0 1.0;
         to_x: "elm.padding.icon";
         to_y: "elm.padding.top";
      }
      rel2 {
         relative: 0.0 0.0;
         to_x: "elm.padding.right";
         to_y: "elm.padding.bottom";
      }
      fixed: 1 0;
      min: 0 LIST_TEXT_MAIN_HEIGHT_INC;
      align: 0.5 0.5;
      text {
         min: 0 1;
         max: 1 1;
         style: "list_text_3text.1icon_main_normal";
         fit: 1 0;
         size: LIST_TEXT_MAIN_SIZE_INC;
         size_range: LIST_TEXT_MAIN_MIN_SIZE_INC LIST_TEXT_MAIN_SIZE_INC;
         ellipsize {
            fade.mode: ON;
            marquee {
               type: ROLL;
               loop: 1;
               loop_delay: MARQUEE_LOOP_DELAY;
               **speed: MARQUEE_SPEED;**
            }
         }
      }
   }

In edc file in 1text group. there is a textblock part for show text.
in the part there is a property for Marquee speed value.
that is for the text scroll speed.

EAPI Eina_Bool
edje_object_part_text_marquee_speed_set(Evas_Object *obj, const char *part, double speed)

And this API can change the property.
```

Comment: Do we have any site where there this `ellipsize` option is documented?

Comment: Also, I'd need `list_text_3text.1icon_main_normal`, and `LIST_TEXT_MAIN_SIZE_INC`, and `LIST_TEXT_MAIN_MIN_SIZE_INC`. Or I really have to clone the whole Tizen branch for changing the marquee speed? :D

Comment: I also don't know how to clone Tizen, as I don't have user for "review.tizen.org". Some information maybe put onto "http://developer.tizen.org/" where I can't register with my gmail email (no emails sent - numerous times I have asked on Facebook).

Comment: 1. Have you checked spam mailbox in your gmail account? I've just tried to made one with gmail, and the confirm mail directly sent in my spam mailbox.
still can't log in review.tizen.org with new created account, it takes time I think..

Comment: 2. As far as I know this ellipsize.marquee is not efl public feature, this is tizen internal feature so there are no document about it. using edc with marquee is only implemented for internal usage, as just kind of text style not a property of list feature currently. it is not meant to be public open for user changing..  so there is no easy way of change this.
only way is customize whole item style new, which is very disrecommended for application developers.

all values you need is in the HVGA-inc.edc of efl-theme-tizen-wearable git.

Comment: I checked new created account in developer.tizen.org works well in review.tizen.org. I miss-typed email address in username, but it was username so I had to put username that I created.

works well and can access below link via new account,
https://review.tizen.org/gerrit/#/admin/projects/profile/wearable/platform/core/uifw/efl-theme-tizen-wearable

still I'm not recommend customizing edc. simply I let you know this way can doable.

Comment: My spam folder doesn't contain any emails from Tizen :/

Comment: Let me ask one more detail: IF I want to have the same effect as original `1text`, ie: top and bottom item is smaller, middle item is normal, but I want to create my own item style (in EDC if that matters), can I somehow reuse system resources?

Comment: Because I want the top and bottom to also display the subtext - not just the main.

Comment: Is the right way for doing this to add my own layout in `listItemClass->func.content_get`?

Answer (score 1):

more additional information about marquee in genlist.
edje_object_part_text_marquee_speed_set
API can be used for edje object to change marquee speed.
yet, genlist item doesn't expose their edje object in any chances,
so you cannot change marquee speed by the API.
only way you can do is customize new genlist item edc refered "1text" style,
and change the marquee speed property.

Comment: Can you please look at my other Tizen issue with SVG: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65939893/svg-is-not-displayed-after-migrating-from-tizen4-to-tizen5-5-neither-in-emulato Sorry for asking this here, but there is no available forum where I can get in touch. JIRA is not working, facebook is handled by a bot. forum is not sending email.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea about svg. but someone else who knows about svg will answer.